# Morse code in a puzzle

Tags: morse-code

I'm working on a morse code geocache puzzle. Firstly I had to listen to Morse code and I got the following words from it

SYGYO UMPET KUSIK MUMWY MOPPE MACOP TUGNY WAAXT MUFAJ MIAMG TUGND

I suspect that these words might be morse code /telegrahic codes with numbers attached and was wondering if anyone could recommend an online source to find out what they mean?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the GC Code.

Comment: Here it is GC6234K

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, these look far more like general "puzzle words" than Morse code abbreviations/prosigns.

- Morse code abbreviations/prosigns generally are three or fewer characters long, or look like obvious abbreviations (e.g. PSE and TNX for "please" and "thanks"). [Here's a list from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code_abbreviations).
- Your list is uniformly five letters per word. This looks very much like a puzzle sort of thing.
- I don't recognize any interesting substrings (even if the first one looks a bit like my callsign, heh).

I think you'll need to look elsewhere for the rest of the puzzle.

Comment: Agreed. Maybe they need to be unscrambled?